# Continuous onto function from $S^{2} \to\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology

My question

- Can we have a continuous onto function from unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a function would be unbounded in the metric topology on $\mathbb{C}$ by the onto condition. But the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is compact, so its image under a continuous map must be bounded; thus it cannot be onto $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is enough to say that $S^2$ is compact, while $\mathbb{C}$ is not compact (of course with the usual euclidean topology).